# In Azure, access to a virtual server via VPN. The virtual server must be closed from public access

Tags: azure, cloud, vpn, azure-vpn

In Azure clouds on the virtual machine (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) I lift the MongoDB server.
The virtual server must be closed from public access
Access to the virtual server via VPN.

In order not to corrupt the VPN server, I try to configure via a Point-to-Site VPN connection.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps

But it is impossible to deal with it.
Maybe there is a simpler method or a simpler manual.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution is to setup **Azure Bastion** on the same VNET as the VM.  Azure Bastion is a fully managed service that provides more secure and seamless Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) and Secure Shell Protocol (SSH) access to virtual machines (VMs) without any exposure through public IP addresses. Provision the service directly in your local or peered virtual network to get support for all the VMs within it.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-bastion/